# Installing Ubuntu Openstack unable to add hardware

Tags: maas, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I'm following the "Installing Ubuntu Openstack" insructions and stuck at step #9. I have 8 servers commissioned and in the "Ready" state. The checklist is all green in Landscape, but there is nothing in the "Add Hardware" section.

No errors or hints as to where to look next. Even if you don't know the answer, if you could suggest log files to review I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This is being handled as a bug report:

https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer/issues/374?